# undefined reference to '__android_log_print'

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, android.mk

I have compiled and ran Android 8 on emulator. I want to view the behavior of ART when installing and opening an application in AOSP. I added this line to dex2aot.cc file:

```
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "native-lib", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOG_TAG "foo"
```

and this one `LOGI("DOOOOOOOOTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");`

```
~Dex2Oat() {
// Log completion time before deleting the runtime_, because this accesses
// the runtime.

LOGI("DOOOOOOOOTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");

LogCompletionTime();
```

I also created android.mk in the dex2aot folder containing this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= liblog
```

Then I run these commands

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng
make -j8
```

And I get `undefined reference` error. I looked up the error, but most solutions are very old. Is there any new solution? Should I modify android.mk in the build folder? I appreciate your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also created android.mk in the dex2oat folder

This does not work. The pattern for declaring a module in an Android.mk would be, e.g. for creating a binary:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
...
LOCAL_MODULE := name_of_your_module
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

This defines a new module `name_of_your_module`, which is of type executable. You could then fill in details about the module in place of the `...`, for example you could add source files with `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ...` or link against shared libraries with `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ...`.

In the code you posted, you gave the `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` declaration, but I do not see a module declaration surrounding it. So the build system has no way of knowing what module wants to link against `liblog`. So when you would want to declare a new module linking against liblog, you would have to make sure that your `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` is in between a `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` and a `LOCAL_MODULE := ...` / `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)` (or an other module type, in case you want to build a static or shared library).

However, this only applies when you want to create a new module. From what I understand, you do not actually want to create a new module, but add a linker dependency to an existing module, namely `dex2oat`. To achieve this, you would have to modify the existing module declaration of `dex2oat`. Now you said you are using Android 8, where this module is in declared in `./art/dex2oat/Android.bp`. Creating a new Android.mk for an existing module declared in a Android.bp will not work. Instead you have to modify the Android.bp.

In `./art/dex2oat/Android.bp`, find the module declaration of `dex2oat`:

```
art_cc_binary {
    name: "dex2oat",
    defaults: [
        "dex2oat-defaults",
    ],
    shared_libs: [
        "libart",
        "libart-compiler",
        "libbase",
        "libsigchain",
    ],
}
```

In the `shared_libs` list, add the library you want to link against, so in your case, `"liblog"`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer. I added liblog to the art_cc_binary you mentioned. It didn't work. I also added this to the other art_cc_binary below it and it compiled successfully. I hope I can see the log in the logcat. Thanks

Comment: Ok, you are right, it seems the dex2oat.cc file you modified is included in multiple modules. So all modules using this source file have to link against liblog. Sorry, I didn't check if other modules were using this file.

Comment: Still your help was huge. Thanks